# ValueError: '0' is not in list when running EXEcutable from Python

Tags: python, list, keyboard, pyinstaller, executable

I have this simple code: notify me with audio and notification tasks every time I press Alt+Shift to switch in one of the four (Italia, Hebrew, English, and Spanish) keyboard layouts.

```
import keyboard
import time
import ctypes
import json
import plyer
import pyttsx3

def on_alt(event):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
        curr_window = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
        thread_id = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(curr_window, 0)
        klid = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
        lid = klid & (2**16 - 1)
        key_list = list(lcid.keys())
        val_list = list(lcid.values())
        position = key_list.index(str(lid))
        
        if(str(lid) == '1040'):
            engine = pyttsx3.init()
            engine.say("Italian")
            engine.runAndWait()
        elif(str(lid) == '1037'):
            engine = pyttsx3.init()
            engine.say("Hebrew")
            engine.runAndWait()
        elif(str(lid) == '2058'):
            engine = pyttsx3.init()
            engine.say("Spanish")
            engine.runAndWait()
        elif(str(lid) == '1033'):
            engine = pyttsx3.init()
            engine.say("English")
            engine.runAndWait()


        plyer.notification.notify(
        title = "Language Keyboard Switch",
        message = str(val_list[position]),
        timeout = 0.1
        )
        
         

lcid = {"1040": "it_IT",
        "1033": "en_US",
        "1037": "he_IL",
        "2058": "es_MX",
}

keyboard.on_press_key('shift', on_alt)
time.sleep(1e6)
```

Running the script as it is, it works fine. But when I build EXEcutable in Windows 10 with pyinstaller it returns this error when I press Alt+Shift

[image: Value '0' not in the list]

It's weird that the same executable built in Windows 11 it works fine.

Comment: Well, it's complaining that `lid = klid & (2**16 - 1)` assigns `0` to `lid` but `0` is not in your list of keys. What is the `klid & (2**16 - 1)` for?

Comment: Doing some debugging it seems like that this operation
klid = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
returns klid = 0 and then everything is 0.